# Filter table and render in shiny based on multiple values from select input

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to filter and render a table in r shiny based of mutiple values from select input. The idea is the user can select multiple values from options `1.Select config` and one value from `2.Select var`. Based of this values it should filter that data from the table `testdata` and render it in mainpanel. What The values in the dropdowns are nothing but a unique of strings from columns `config` and `var`. Below is the code with the data. So the user selects multiple values from first dropdown, one value from second dropdown and when clicked on select it should show the table.

```
library(shiny)
testdata <- tibble::tribble(
  ~config,       ~construct, ~var,
  "alpha,beta", "This is line 1",   12,
  "beta,gamma,alpha", "This is line 2",   15,
  "delta,alpha,tetra", "This is line 3",   21,
  "quad,core ,delta", "This is line 4",   12,
  "alpha,gamma", "This is line 5",   12,
  "beta,core", "This is line 5",   11,
  "delta,quad,tetra", "This is line 5",   21,
  "quad,tetra", "This is line 5",   12
)
config <- unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(testdata$config), ",")))
var <- unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(testdata$var), ",")))

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'Selectize examples',
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      selectizeInput(
        'e2', '1.Select Config', choices = config, multiple = TRUE
      ),
      selectizeInput(
        'e3', '2. Select Var', choices = var, multiple = TRUE
      ),
      br(), 

      actionButton('select', 'Select')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      width = 10,
      DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "mtable")

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  filtered_year <- reactive({
    filter(testdata, (config %in% input$e2) &
             (var %in% input$e3)
) 
  })

  fully_filtered <- eventReactive(input$select, {
    filtered_year()
  })

  output$mtable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(data = fully_filtered(), options = list(pageLength = 10),
                  rownames = FALSE, class = 'display', escape = FALSE)

  })
  output$ex_out <- renderPrint({
    a <- str(sapply('e2', function(id) {
      input[[id]]
    }, simplify = FALSE))
    a
    print(a)
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Updated Code: Added to show the table which doesnt display filtered values.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you need?  Also, if you only want the user to be able to select one value from the second dropdown, you should use `multiple = FALSE`.

```
library(shiny)
testdata <- tibble::tribble(
  ~config,       ~construct, ~var,
  "alpha,beta", "This is line 1",   12,
  "beta,gamma,alpha", "This is line 2",   15,
  "delta,alpha,tetra", "This is line 3",   21,
  "quad,core ,delta", "This is line 4",   12,
  "alpha,gamma", "This is line 5",   12,
  "beta,core", "This is line 5",   11,
  "delta,quad,tetra", "This is line 5",   21,
  "quad,tetra", "This is line 5",   12
)
config <- unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(testdata$config), ",")))
var <- unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(testdata$var), ",")))

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'Selectize examples',
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      selectizeInput(
        'e2', '1.Select Config', choices = config, multiple = TRUE
      ),
      selectizeInput(
        'e3', '2. Select Var', choices = var, multiple = TRUE
      ),
      br(), 

      actionButton('select', 'Select')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      width = 10,
      DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "mtable")

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$select, {
    print(input$e2)
    print(input$e3)
    fully_filtered <- testdata[grepl(paste(input$e2, collapse = "|"), testdata$config) &
                                 testdata$var %in% input$e3,]

    output$mtable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(data = fully_filtered, options = list(pageLength = 10),
                    rownames = FALSE, class = 'display', escape = FALSE)

    })
  })

  output$ex_out <- renderPrint({
    a <- str(sapply('e2', function(id) {
      input[[id]]
    }, simplify = FALSE))
    a
    print(a)
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```